# How do I check whether the img src is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

This case :

```
<img id = 'img1' src ="a.jpg" />


$('#img1').attr('src','b.jpg');
```

Dynamically change the image resource, the resource will be reloaded then, the problem is , how to check whether the reload is finish by id / img path etc...?? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tap into the [`load` event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/):

```
$("img").load(function () {
    alert('loaded!');
});
$("img").attr("src", "b.jpg");
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/6zAN7/4/

Comment: Thanks, but how to change it as if statment? since I may have more than 1 case .  eg. do something only if #img2 and #img3 finish loaded

Comment: @user782104: You want to wait for multiple images to load? You could simply use a counter and check and see if it equals two each time the load event fires.